# What's a clean way to pass context down functions?

Tags: python, multithreading, locking

I'm trying to manage synchronized file operations using locks as context. However, I end up blocking forever when one function calls another that needs the lock.

For example:

```
from threading import Lock
lock = Lock()


def foo():
    print('foo')
    with lock:
        print('foo-locked')
        bar()


def bar():
    print('bar')
    with lock:
        print("bar-locked")  # Will not print since lock is owned by foo()

foo()
```

Is there a clean way to pass the context of one function to another? I'd rather not send the lock as an argument - then I'd be using context managers in some functions and not in others.

Comment: To me it seems a conflict in design to attempt to call a lock-using function from within the lock of another function. Try to design code parts/functions which are non-overlapping, then you can use a lock to ensure mutual exclusion.

Comment: Are you aware your example is single-threaded so using a lock makes no sense here?

Comment: Yup! Just meant to contextualize the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could consider using a re-entrant lock ([Threading.RLock](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#rlock-objects)). As long as the 2 functions that need the lock are in the same thread, they will be able to proceed.

Comment: This might not solve all use-cases, but it definitely helped mine!